# Add the leading zero before a decimal

Tags: microsoft-excel, format

I have a column that stores a decimal likes this:

```
 0.345
-0.013
- ,007
  ,080
```

but I want to format it to the same type likes this:

```
 0.345
-0.013
-0,007
 0,080
```

I think that the format type should be:

```
#,##0.000
```

But I have tried and it does not work. Also, I have searched from SO and some Excel sites but got nothing, they talked about removing or adding before text...

Anyone knows how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your Windows regional settings use the `dot` for a decimal separator; I dunno what you use for the thousands separator -- in the US we use a comma.

That being the case, the values which appear to show a comma as a decimal separator are likely text strings.  You will NOT be able to retain that and still have the values properly formatted and useful as numbers (at least not easily and downstream formulas will have to be modified extensively).

What you can do is convert the "comma" values to real numbers, and then format them with the code you show.

eg:

```
B1: =--SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",".")
```

And fill down.

Then use the custom format of your choice (e.g `#,##0.000` as shown in the screenshot):

[image]

If your windows regional settings are different than what I assume, we may need to make some slight modifications in the formula.